# Find file that does not contain specific string

Tags: perl

I want to find file that does not contain the specific string?
The listed file is like below

```
../../../experiment/fileA.txt (contain word 'Book')
../../../experiment/fileB.txt (contain word 'Book')
../../../experiment/fileC.txt (do not contain word 'Book')
../../../experiment/fileD.txt (contain word 'Book')
```

Here is my code

```
use strict;
use warning;

my $dirname = "../../../experiment/";
my $keyword = "Book";
my @result;

my $find_file = sub {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;
    if ($F =~ /txt$/) {
       open my $in, "<", $F or die $!;
       while(<$in>) {
          if (/\Q$keyword\E/){
             next;
          }else{
             push @result, $F;
             return;          
          }
      }
   }  
};

find ({ wanted => $find_file, no_chdir=>1}, $dirname );
foreach my $result (@result){
   chomp $result;
   $result =~ s{.*/}{};
   print "$result\n";
}
```

But it seem does not work. It display all file whether it has the $keyword or not. I only want it to display only if the file does not have the $keyword

Comment: What defines `@keyword`? Add `use strict;` to the top of your script. also you may just want to join your keywords together with `|` for use in the regex without a `for` loop, it will be more efficient using alternation that way.

Comment: Hi @DavidO sorry for inconvinience. I already update my code.

Comment: The updated code appears to work if you change `print OUTPUT "$result\n";` to `print "$result\n";` If you put `use warnings;` at the top you'll get "print to unopened file handle" warning.

Comment: Sorry, i use to minimize the code, i already remove. still result is same

Comment: The problem, then, is not demonstrated by the code you provided. Perhaps you are looking in a non-existent directory, or one that you don't have privs on. Change your `wanted` sub to just `print "$File::Find::name\n" if -f $File::Find::name;`, and nothing else. Do you see any files listed? Anyway, we can't answer this question because it fails to demonstrate the problem you describe if used on paths that exist, and files that contain the trigger text. It's unanswerable.

Comment: By the way, on a Linux system or any system with GNU grep and find, you can solve this easily from the command line.  grep has the -l and -v options, for example.

Comment: hi @DavidO , yes, there is file listed. But it listed all file including the file that have $keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simple logic error. The code goes through lines of each file

```
while (<$in>) {
    if (/\Q$keyword\E/){
        next;
    } else {
        push @result, $F;
        return;          
    }
}
```

and as soon as *any one line* doesn't have `$keyword` it adds the file to `@result`.

You need to check all lines and if `$keyword` is never found only then add a file.  The easiest way to do this is to `return` from the sub as soon as the thing is found

```
while (<$in>) {
    return if /\Q$keyword/;
}

push @result, $F;
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address your code, but I'd like to point out that with the `grep` command on any Linux system you can do exactly what it looks like you're trying to do with this command:

```
grep -L Book -R ../../../experiment/
```

Comment: Thanks for sugesstion. but i need to use perl in this case

Answer (score 1):

[Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule) makes tasks like this really simple. As a side note, I would recommend resolving the directory to an absolute path before iterating.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use File::Basename;
use Path::Iterator::Rule;

my $dirname = abs_path "../../../experiment/";
my $keyword = "Book";

my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->not_dir->name(qr/txt$/)->not_line_match(qr/\Q$keyword\E/);
my $next = $rule->iter($dirname);
while (defined(my $file = $next->())) {
  print basename($file), "\n";
}
```